# Doxygen docs installation fails due to EPSTOPDF-NOTFOUND error

Tags: cmake, latex, doxygen, tex

I'm trying to build the Doxygen documentation. I can get the html files to build and load properly in the borwser. However, the PDF files do not build properly.

When I execute `make docs` (as stated in the Doxygen installation instructions), the following is the error output:

```
[ 37%] Built target _doxygen
[ 38%] Built target md5
[ 38%] Built target lodepng
[ 45%] Built target mscgen
[ 45%] Checking the git repository for changes...
[ 45%] Built target check_git_repository
[ 46%] Checking the doxygen version for changes...
[ 46%] Built target check_doxygen_version
[ 47%] Built target doxygen_version
[ 55%] Built target qtools
[ 55%] Built target generate_configvalues_header
[ 57%] Built target vhdlparser
[ 61%] Built target doxycfg
[ 61%] Built target doxygen
[ 85%] Built target examples
[ 85%] Generating Latex and HTML documentation.
[100%] Built target run_doxygen
[100%] Generating Doxygen Manual PDF.
/bin/sh: 1: EPSTOPDF-NOTFOUND: not found
doc/CMakeFiles/doxygen_pdf.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'doc/CMakeFiles/doxygen_pdf' failed
make[3]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/doxygen_pdf] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:637: recipe for target 'doc/CMakeFiles/doxygen_pdf.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/doxygen_pdf.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:671: recipe for target 'doc/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:379: recipe for target 'docs' failed
make: *** [docs] Error 2
```

I have searched online extensively and installed all font packages I can find regarding the TexLive package, and I have installed the `pdflatex` package as well.

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You were able to build doxygen, and the HTML documentation, but the building the PDF documentation fails. During the configuration phase it is determined where `epstopdf` resides. Did you install TexLive packages before or after the doxygen configuration (cmake)? (epstopdf should be in the texlive-font-utils package according my quick search), when after doxygen configuration rerun the configuration. What is the result of `which epstopdf` ? and of `eps2pdf --version`?

Comment: @albert
Thank you, you helped me solve the problem. I ran the `cmake -Dbuild_doc=YES ..
` and `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` commands again, as I had not run them since installing all the TexLive recommended and extra fonts.